# Can we optimize the Oracle query further?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

This query is taking 2.17 sec of time and no. of rows in output are 128000.All the source tables have approx 100k rows.But the same query some times takes more time during Production hours, which is the cause of slowness in system, as seen in Top 5 highly time taking queries in Oracle 11g. Can we optimize it further.

**Note** : Indexes are created for all the columns used in Where and On conditions. Also find attached query plan.

```
    SELECT (ROWNUM)ROWNUMBER, RES.* 
                  FROM         
                  (SELECT PIDS,        
                  FILENUM,
                  FILETYPE,
                  ATT,        
                  FILESTA,        
                  WSNAME,        
                  CMP5.CLT_NAME AS CLIENT,        
                  CLT_CODE,
                  CLTREF,
                  TMTYPE,
                  ASSOCNAME,
                  FFCOUNTRY,
                  APPLICATIONNO,
                  FF_APPLICATIONNO,
                  FILING_TRADEMARKTITLE,
                  FF_TRADEMARKTITLE,
                  QUERY_TRADEMARKTITLE,
                  CMP6.DOCNAME AS SEARCH_TRADEMARKTITLE,
                  CMP7.DOCUMENTNAME as FF_SEARCH_TRADEMARK,
                  CMP.CLASS AS CLASSES,        
                  CMP4.CLASS AS CLASSESFF,        
                  CMP2.NAME             AS PROPRIETER,        
                  CMP2.CODE             AS PROPRIETERCODE,
                  CMP5.CNTRY AS CNTRY,
                  CMP5.STATE AS STATE,
                  CMP5.CITY AS CITY         
                  FROM        
                  (SELECT EXT.PID         AS PIDS,            
                  EXT.FILE_NUMBER       AS FILENUM,
                  EXT.proceeding_assignmenttype       AS FILETYPE,
                  EXT.ATTORNEY          AS ATT,          
                  EXT.FILE_STATUS        AS FILESTA,            
                  CURRENTWS AS WSNAME,         
                  EXT.CLIENT_CODE       AS CLT_CODE,
                  EXT.client_ref       AS CLTREF,
                  EXT.FP_APP_TYPE       AS TMTYPE,
                  EXT.ff_nameofassociate       AS ASSOCNAME,
                  EXT.ff_nameofcountry       AS FFCOUNTRY,
                  EXT.filing_trademarkno   AS APPLICATIONNO,
                  EXT.ff_trademarknumber   AS FF_APPLICATIONNO,
                  EXT.FILING_TRADEMARK AS FILING_TRADEMARKTITLE,
                  EXT.FF_TRADMARK AS FF_TRADEMARKTITLE,
                  EXT.Q_TRADEMARK AS QUERY_TRADEMARKTITLE
                  FROM EXT_TRADEMARK EXT         
                  WHERE CURRENTWSSTATUS = '1'      
                  ORDER BY EXT.FILE_NUMBER DESC
                  )EXTTABLE         
                  LEFT JOIN COMPLEX_TM_CLASS CMP         
                  ON EXTTABLE.PIDS = CMP.PROCESSINSTANCEID                           
                  LEFT JOIN COMPLEX_TM_PROPRIEATOR CMP2         
                  ON EXTTABLE.PIDS = CMP2.PROCESSINSTANCEID     
                  LEFT JOIN COMPLEX_TM_FF_CLASS CMP4         
                  ON EXTTABLE.PIDS = CMP4.PROCESSINSTANCEID         
                  LEFT JOIN FA_CLT_MSTR CMP5
                  ON EXTTABLE.CLT_CODE = CMP5.CLT_COD
                  LEFT JOIN COMPLEX_TM_SEARCH CMP6         
                  ON EXTTABLE.PIDS = CMP6.PID
                  LEFT JOIN COMPLEX_TM_FF_SEARCH CMP7         
                  ON EXTTABLE.PIDS = CMP7.PID order by FILENUM desc
                  ) RES ;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can begin with removing the nested subquery. It is totally unnecessary. Also, what is the type of the column `CURRENTWSSTATUS` ? If it is a number you should not use the single quotes as this will do implicit conversion which extremely slow. If it is a varchar column and you only have number on it, consider in changing its type.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos for your comment. We have alphanumeric values in CURRENTWSSTATUS  column. And replacing sub-query directly with table name can improve the performance.Right?. Will share the result here.

Comment: Yes it will improve it for sure. Also, in your explain plan there is no mention of indexes in use. Create indexes for table/column that is in use in the left join operations. This will improve even better.